# Jar hell for missing classes folder when running ESRestTestCase

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, integration-testing

So I'm running into a Jar hell problem when trying to run individual integration tests, using `-Dtest=`, that runs as a ESRestTestCase (ESTestCase). The issue here seems to be that some elasticsearch classpath validation class requires target/classes to exist. However, this project is only for testing so that requirement doesn't make sense.

This happened with Elasticsearch 7.0.0 and Java 1.8.0.251. Not sure if this is a problem with later versions.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:229)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:623)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: <MY PROJECT FOLDER PATH HERE>/target/classes
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:199)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:96)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried various methods for making sure the classes folder was still created. I ran into [new problems that seemed fixed in later versions](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33045) so I upgraded to Elasticsearch 7.6.2 (And lucene 8.4.0). Upgrading seemed to remove the need for the folder to exist but triggered other issues ([similar to this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33045)). I worked around such issues with `-Dtests.security.manager=false`. Then I got [thread leak issues](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/integration-testing-in-java-carrotsearch-thread-leaks-severe-errors/26831) which I "solved" by setting `@ThreadLeakScope(ThreadLeakScope.Scope.NONE)` on the test class.

Then finally it seemed to work when running maven in command line for individual tests. But when trying to run the maven task with debugger in Intellij the debugger does not seem to attach.

So I try to run it as JUnit templated test in Intellij. Here I get jar hell when running it but it *works to debug*. The jar hell was later solved by setting `idea.no.launcher=true` in `idea.properties`.

Alright, good enough for now. These workarounds are far from ideal but it works for my current purposes. A lot of things will change before moving into mainline anyway. And maybe this will help someone else. Hopefully I can post a better solution later.